# Creating DX11 shaders from string

Tags: shader, directx-11

I have not been able to find anything about this, and I am not sure whether or not it is actually doable, but here goes:

I'd like to be able to provide a shader with my DX11 game, one which is not loaded from file (since then, that file would have to be included with eeeeevery project using my framework). I want to use the content of the HLSL file directly. I did try this, but it gave me E_INVALIDARG back.

Here is the code:

```
auto pixelShaderByteCode = std::string("struct PixelShaderInput" \
  "{" \
  "float4 pos : SV_POSITION;" \
  "float3 color : COLOR0;" \
  "};" \
  "float4 main(PixelShaderInput input) : SV_TARGET" \
  "{" \
  "return float4(input.color, 1.0f);" \
  "}");

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11PixelShader> ps;

auto hr = m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreatePixelShader(
  pixelShaderByteCode.c_str(),
  pixelShaderByteCode.length(),
  nullptr,
  &ps);

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    // that did not work... hr = E_INVALIDARG
}
```

Is it the fact that I would need a compiled shader for this to work? If so, what would be the best practice for "baking" shaders into an engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call the `CreatePixelShader` method with the HLSL source. You have to compile it to a binary shader blob *first*.

```
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3DBlob> blob;
HRESULT hr = D3DCompile(
    pixelShaderByteCode.c_str(),
    pixelShaderByteCode.length(),
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    "main", "ps_4_0",
    D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, 0,
    &blob;
    nullptr);
if (FAILED(hr))
    ...

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11PixelShader> ps;
hr = m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreatePixelShader(
    blob.GetBufferPointer(),
    blob.GetBufferSize(),
    nullptr,
    &ps);
if (FAILED(hr))
    ...
```

> Note a better answer is compile your shaders offline and have the binary blob generated as a C array in a C source header file using [fxc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509709.aspx) and the `/Fh` parameter. You then include that header which puts the shader data into your program directly. See [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/tree/master/Src/Shaders) which uses this approach.

Comment: Putting the compiled shader into a header file works like a charm. Thank you for mentioning this, exactly what I was after.